# Magento 1.9 /checkout/cart/ 301

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, http-status-code-301

I am using magento 1.9. All the pages are working, but only the cart page goes to 301 error. Please help me to fix.

```
curl -i http://local.lg.dev/checkout/cart/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2016 08:13:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.9
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: /checkout/cart/
```

Comment: 301 isn't an error. Where does the page send you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?